# Inertia Laravel me devuelve un json y no renderiza la pagina

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, inertia.js

Después de visitar páginas en inglés y en español y sin encontrar muchos resultados, recurro a stack overflow para ver si alguien puede ayudarme. Hay una pregunta similar a la mía pero nadie le contesto [esta es la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484800/evitar-mostrar-respuesta-del-servidor-inertia-laravel-vue).

En mi caso, lo único que quiero es que al enviar el array del controlador se renderice en la página de restaurantes que están dentro del rango de distancia con los datos que envio.

Este es el controlador:

```html
class RestaurantController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
//        $restaurants = Restaurant::all();
        $userLocationLat = $request->input('lat');
        $userLocationLng = $request->input('lng');
        $distance = $request->input('distance');

        //Creamos un array para que cuando la distancia este dentro de donde queremos aparezca el restaurante
        $availableRestaurants = [];

        foreach (Restaurant::all() as $restaurant){
            $distanceBetweenLocations = $this->getDistance($restaurant->lat, $restaurant->lng, $userLocationLat, $userLocationLng);
            if ($distanceBetweenLocations <= $distance)
                return  $availableRestaurants[] = $restaurant;

        }
        $restaurants = $availableRestaurants;
//        dd($restaurant);
        return Inertia::render('Restaurant/index', ['restaurants'=>$availableRestaurants]);
    }

    private function getDistance($point1_lat, $point1_long, $point2_lat, $point2_long, $unit = 'mi', $decimals = 2) {
        // Calculate the distance in degrees
        $degrees = rad2deg(acos((sin(deg2rad($point1_lat))*sin(deg2rad($point2_lat))) + (cos(deg2rad($point1_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point2_lat))*cos(deg2rad($point1_long-$point2_long)))));

        // Convert the distance in degrees to the chosen unit (kilometres, miles or nautical miles)
        switch($unit) {
            case 'km':
                $distance = $degrees * 111.13384; // 1 degree = 111.13384 km, based on the average diameter of the Earth (12,735 km)
                break;
            case 'mi':
                $distance = $degrees * 69.05482; // 1 degree = 69.05482 miles, based on the average diameter of the Earth (7,913.1 miles)
                break;
            case 'nmi':
                $distance =  $degrees * 59.97662; // 1 degree = 59.97662 nautic miles, based on the average diameter of the Earth (6,876.3 nautical miles)
        }
        return round($distance, $decimals);
    }
}
```

En la parte de front, utilizo vue, donde cojo los datos de la api de google maps y utilizo axios para coger los datos:

```html
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <h1 class="text-8xl">Buscar restaurantes</h1>
    <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" >Autocomplete Google Maps</label>
<!--        <input type="hidden" v-model="form.postal_code" name="postal_code" id="postcode">-->
        <input type="hidden" v-model="form.lat" name="lat" id="lat">
        <input type="hidden" v-model="form.lng" name="lng" id="lng">
    <GMapAutocomplete @place_changed="setPlace"  class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700
    border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
       />

        <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Distance</label>
        <select name="distance" v-model="form.distance" id="distance" class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">
            <option value="1">1 mile</option>
            <option value="2">2 mile</option>
            <option value="3">3 mile</option>
            <option value="4">4 mile</option>
            <option value="5">5 mile</option>
            <option value="10">10 mile</option>
            <option value="50">50 mile</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" @click="submit()">Buscar</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import VueGoogleMaps from "@fawmi/vue-google-maps";
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";
export default {
    name: "SearchField",
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
              lat: '',
              lng: '',
            },

            // autocompleteOptions: {
            //     componentRestrictions: {
            //         country: [
            //             'es',
            //         ],
            //     },
            // },
        }
    },
    components:{
        VueGoogleMaps,
    },
    methods: {
        setPlace(place) {
            this.form = place;
            this.form.lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            this.form.lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        },
      async  submit() {
            // Inertia.visit(route('restaurants.search', this.form)),
              await axios.post(route('restaurants.search'), this.form).then(response => {
                      this.form = response.data
                  console.log(this.form)
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.error(err+'esto es un error')
                });
        },

    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Y está es la respuesta que me devuelve al darle al botón buscar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte del index.vue que es donde debería pintarse los datos tengo lo siguiente, sin embargo no se pintan:

```html
<template>
    <AppLayout>
        <h1>HOLA</h1>
        <div v-for="restaurant in restaurants" :key="restaurant.id" class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">

            <div class="px-6 py-4">
                <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{ restaurant.name }}</div>
                <p class="text-gray-700 text-base">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus quia, nulla! Maiores et perferendis eaque, exercitationem praesentium nihil.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
                <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#photography</span>
                <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#travel</span>
                <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#winter</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>

</template>

<script>
import AppLayout from "../../Layouts/AppLayout";
export default {
    name: "index",
    // props: ['restaurants'],
    props: {
      restaurants: Object
    },
    components: {AppLayout}
}
</script>
```

Y por último tengo en web.php el post:

```html
Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/dashboard/restaurants', [RestaurantController::class,'index'])->name('restaurants.search');
//    Route::get('/dashboard/restaurants',[RestaurantController::class,'index']
//    )->name('restaurants.search');
});
```

¿Cómo puedo renderizar los datos en la pantalla de index restaurantes sin que inertia me salte con el error de

> All Inertia requests must receive a valid Inertia response, however a plain JSON response was received

o el axios solo me devuelva el console.log?